# AdminLte remove Ready to sell your theme

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, adminlte

Is there any possible way to remove

"Ready to sell your theme? Submit your theme to our new marketplace now and let over 200k visitors see it!Let's Do It!
"
from AdminLte .

Below is the image of message.

[image: AdminLte]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can remove following line from `adminlte.min.js` to solve your problem.

```
$('.content-wrapper').prepend(wrapper)
```